# Qgis 3.14 can not make mssql connection OK button grey out

Tags: sql-server, button, connection, qgis

I want to make a MSSQL connection but i can not press the OK button.
This is grey out. Can someone help me out ????

[Make new mssql connection screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5sin.png)

Comment: This is about General Computing and Software --  It is a better suited question for [Super User](https://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Type anything in the DSN box and save.  Close QGIS. Locate QGIS3.ini.  Simply delete the text you entered from the appropriate line in QGIS3.ini  Restart QGIS and all should be OK.

Comment: He or She has a problem with connection, and didn't mention about GIS plugin in MSSQL. And you suggest to turn off another program which uses database? Have you asked him or her about QGis?

Comment: Thanks I solved the problem. Like Tony says I type anything in the DNS box and save it. After this i chose menu Extra then Options and Advance. Then chose MSSQL > Connections. Chose the connection to edit. Remove service value.

Comment: This worked for me too, but rather than editing the .ini file, I did as @NvBgm suggested; Options | Advanced